# React Flow ESlint: parsing error unexpected token, expected ','

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am trying to use Flow alongside ESlint in React. I have a basic Container component that takes a children prop. Here is the component code:

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'react-emotion';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: hsl(181, 54%, 44%);
  color: hsl(221, 51%, 34%);
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
`;

export default function Container({ children: React.Node }) {
  return <Wrapper>{children}</Wrapper>;
}
```

The eslint parser chokes on the flow type annotation React.Node, giving this error:

[View error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj7HT.png)

Am I missing something here? I would like to be able to use Flow types while still taking advantage of ESlint.

Comment: You might need to import the type separately`import React, type { Node } from 'react';`